# Raspbian owncloud nginx [error] 2667#0: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: php, linux, nginx, raspbian

I am using a Raspberry pi to host a owncloud server. It uses nginx, and when I configured the pi with [this tutorial](http://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-owncloud/), the page came up with a 502 Bad Gateway error.  I checked the logs and found this:

> 2015/10/22 05:18:03 [error] 2667#0: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.101, server: 192.168.1.102, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.102", referrer: "https://192.168.1.102/"

EDIT: Nevermind this question anymore, I have moved on to using a different platform. However, I am still urious as to what this problem is.

I tried to fix it with several other solutions found in posts on this site like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524373/nginx-connect-failed-111-connection-refused-while-connecting-to-upstream) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852884/nginx-connect-failed-error), as well as ensuring that php was installed, but none worked. I am stumped as I am a relative newbie to linux and know nothing about nginx.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524373/nginx-connect-failed-111-connection-refused-while-connecting-to-upstream)

Answer (score 0):

The php-fpm is not running. You should run the php-fpm.
If you has add the php-fpm as a service : service php-fpm restart
Or {PHP_PATH}/sbin/php-fpm    {PHP_PATH} is the --with-prefix=/path/ when you ./configure the php